# Can a Muslimah be a fireman?

Tags: halal-haram, profession

AsSalamu Alaykum, Jumaah Mubarak.  Insha'Allah can someone give me Quran on why a woman cannot be a firewoman? And why is it okay for her to be a firewoman? Married? and Non Married?
Jazak Allah

Comment: Everything is by default mobaah (permissible}. So what makes you think it shouldn't be?

Comment: Why cant you be a firewoman? Where did you get that from?